# Properly comparing datastore keys in node

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

It appears that `@google-cloud/datastore` doesn't provide a method for comparing keys, and keys themselves aren't comparable. Is there a proper way to compare keys? I've taken a few stabs myself:

```
function compare(key1, key2) {
    return (key1.kind == key2.kind) && (key1.id == key2.id)
}
```

However, this doesn't work for keys with ancestors or keys with only kinds. So something more general might look like

```
function compare(key1, key2) {
    if (key1.path.length != key2.path.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < key1.path.length; i++) {
        if (key1.path[i] != key2.path[i]) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

These solutions seem to work, but are kinda ugly to have laying around. Is there just a built in function I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything. There is no built in implementation of the key comparsion for datastore. I believe this is because it might be highly depends from business logic.

I'm using this implementation.

```
/**
 * Compare two keys on equality
 * @param {Object} key1 
 * @param {Object} key2 
 * @return {boolean}
 */
function compareKeys (key1, key2) {
    return key1.namespace === key2.namespace && _.isEqual(key1.path, key2.path); 
}
```

**Update**

I've created simple npm module in order to not copy/paste such solution everywhere.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/datastore-key-compare

Comment: Namespaces! Thanks for pointing out I missed yet another important part of the key!

Comment: Maybe you will be interested in answer update. Just created an npm module for keys comparison.